# Why does gibbon throw 'uninitialized constant Gibbon::API (NameError)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

I'm trying to add the [gibbon gem](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) into a Rails 3.2 app.

I've followed the instructions, and set up a gibbon.rb initializer with the following

```
Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
```

The app is throwing

```
uninitialized constant Gibbon::API (NameError)
```

I've tried to `require 'gibbon'` amongst other things, but nothing seems to work.

Why is the class not initialized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong version of the gem.

Github sports a shiney new version 0.5, while rubygems is still on v. 0.4.

Installing from `git: 'git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git'` solved everything!

facepalm!

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AndyHarvey. If you're using bundler, use this in your Gemfile: `gem 'gibbon', git: 'git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git'` to install from Github. Sometimes I think about what programming would be like without StackOverflow, and I weep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Gibbon's maintainer. Sorry for the trouble. I've updated the [readme](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) (Thanks Charles) to reflect the fact that 0.4.x is the current release and linked to its readme (most recent pre 0.5.x commit). In the future I'll be sure to create a new branch so as not to confuse people.

Version 0.5.0 is still in testing but should be released very soon. The docs are different because it hits a new version of MailChimp's API, which is substantially different from the old API.

Comment: Thanks for updating to 2.0, I'm using Gibbon for the first time and so far no problems with 0.5.0

Comment: 0.5.0 has been released